# Migrate encryption key from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I'm currently trying to update from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3. But now I have a problem with transforming the encryption from MCrypt to OpenSSL as described in the upgrade guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0 here. For this purpose I wrote a command as suggested in the docs above. But there's an error:

```
[2016-09-18 11:07:46] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException' with message 'The payload is invalid.' in /home/vagrant/Code/bob/vendor/laravel/legacy-encrypter/src/BaseEncrypter.php:44
```

Command:

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Laravel\LegacyEncrypter\McryptEncrypter;

class McryptToOpenSSL extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'key:migrate';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Migrates key from deprecated Mcrypt to OpenSSL.';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $legacy = new McryptEncrypter(env('APP_KEY_LEGACY'));
    $users  = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->password = encrypt(
            $legacy->decrypt($user->password)
        );

        $user->save();
    }
}
}
```

.env (keys are slightly changed for security reasons)

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:3VU8u79ZU0dObazwvd2lHHOAVRJjy5kvzXKeKtcHVYk=
APP_KEY_LEGACY=zejqrdy7WjA58xGoSuj634RYXB97vLyp
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you manually overriding user's password encryption?
By default if you don't change anything, you don't need to do that migration of password.
password is not using encrypt() to encrypt, it's using password_hash(),
and that's the reason payload is not valid.